# How to show notification by using socket in java swing

Tags: java, swing, socket.io, notifications

I am developing a java swing based application which is install some computer and connected by LAN.I can transfer files between them by using socket.Now I wanted to show as a notification when someone receive any file by socket.

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6928);
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

    int filesCount = dis.readInt();
    File[] files = new File[filesCount];
```

By above code ,I can receive file from other PC.Now I want to show that as a notification in server side.

Comment: Is this your swing application? Have you created any UI for notification?

Comment: Yes, It is a swing based project and have Number(Show in JLabel)  that increases when server receive any file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TrayIcon class. Consider the following example, the TrayIcon object is created and added it in SystemTray. Mouse click action is attached to the TrayIcon, click event shows the notification. You can also use the showNotification method to show the notification.

Now in your code, when you receive the file from server, call showNotification 
 method with the data you want to show on the notification.

```
static Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("<Image Path>"); //System Tray Icon

    static TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Test");

    public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
        if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

            trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
            trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Test!", "Mouse Clicked", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                };
            });

            try {
                tray.add(trayIcon);
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                System.err.println("TrayIcon not Added");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void showNotification(String title, String msg, String location) {
        if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            trayIcon.displayMessage(title, msg, TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
        }
    }
```